# How long should scaling service fabric take?

Tags: azure, scaling, azure-service-fabric

I started a scale change on my service fabric cluster about 2 hours ago - i've gone form the default to Standard_A1_v2 (5 instances) having ran out of disk space due to log files created by the run time!!

Should my service really be down this long or is it more likely that there has been a problem and I'll need to recreate the cluster? This is no casual task so I would rather not have to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Your VM SKU is too low.

> For production workloads
>
> The recommended VM SKU is Standard D3 or Standard D3_V2 or equivalent
>   with a minimum of 14 GB of local SSD. The minimum supported use VM SKU
>   is Standard D1 or Standard D1_V2 or equivalent with a minimum of 14 GB
>   of local SSD.  Partial core VM SKUs like Standard A0 are not supported
>   for production workloads. Standard A1 SKU is specifically not
>   supported for production workloads for performance reasons

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity).

Comment: OK going to give that a try on a new cluster - the original one seems completely FUBAR

Comment: I had a very similar issue, basically I had to recreate the cluster with D1_v2 machines then scale down to A1. In the end I opted for buying a cheap PC and setting us up a development cluster within it (hyper v machines) as these A1 machines were glacially slow.